# Adverse Events table in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I have the following SAS data set:

```
Subject        AETERM1        AETERM2         TREATMENT
001            Illness        Fever           0
001            Illness        Cold            0
002            Cardiac        AFIB            1
003            Cardiac        AFLUT           1
```

I would like to create a table like this in SAS:

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________________
    AETERM1
       AETERM2            TREATMENT = 0 (N = 1)     TREATMENT = 1 (N = 2)    OVERALL (N = 3)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Any Event                 1 (100%)                  2 (100%)                  3 (100%)
Illness                   1 (100%)                                            1 (33%)
    Fever                 1 (100%)                                            1 (33%)
    Cold                  1 (100%)                                            1 (33%)
Cardiac                                              2 (100%)                 2 (67%)
    AFIB                                             1 (50%)                  1 (33%)   
    AFLUT                                            1 (50%)                  1 (33%)
```

I'm able to generate something close with the following PROC FREQ statement:

```
proc freq data = have order = freq;
table aeterm1 * aeterm2 / missing;
run;
```

Comment: There's a paper called 'creating complex reports' by Cynthia Zender that covers creating tables like this. It's one of the examples and the paper also has code to follow along or to use as a starter for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually use

```
proc freq data = have order = freq;
  table aeterm1 * aeterm2 * treatment / out = results;
run;
```

and process the `results` dataset to get the view you want